# Minifying Craft HTML templates

Tags: templating

Has anyone successfully minified Craft's HTML templates?

Had setup a Grunt task but it had parse issues with the twig template tags. I since found that the Grunt task "HTMLmin" is only for the purposes of minifying "vanilla" HTML.

Is this even possible?

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a plugin I made that does just that:

https://github.com/khalwat/minify

Answer (score 6):

There are [several](https://github.com/johndwells/craft.minimee) [plugins](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/compressor) that will [minify/compress](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/automin) CSS/JS for you.

But for HTML, maybe you're better off just [enabling gzip compression](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html) on your web server for all output.